# What is the best way to learn Blender?

Tags: modeling, rendering, animation, mesh, texturing

I have no prior experience with graphics at all. I only found Blender useful and interesting, and as a result, started trying to make use of it.

I want to master skills like modeling, animation and texturing.

What will be the best way to learn and master this very good tool? Are there any resources that would be useful?

Comment: I would say follow the tutorials you can find on youtube, and begin by the beginning, like modeling, then material and textures, then animation, then rigging, then physics, etc...

Comment: Also, don't just watch beginner tutorials.  Watch intermediate and even advanced tutorials (not necessarily following along).  You won't absorb everything, in fact you will miss more than half of what is said, but you will be introduced to capabilities and techniques that will come in useful later.  I would alternate among following along with simple tutorials, watching more advanced tutorials, and trying to model things on your own without following a tutorial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a beginner myself, I think the best way to learn blender is by trying to model something you find interesting. That way, you're going to know what you want to do, and then know what tutorial you should search on the internet.

Because only following tutorial from chapter 1 to end is going to be boring, if you don't know what you want to make or project based.

Just try to model something, and when you don't know how to do what you want to do, google it. I've come pretty far compared to when I was starting by using this method.

Comment: I already see myself achieving much very quickly. Thank you.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions on exercises for me?

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend the Blender for Beginners tutorial by Blender Guru (free on youtube) it is sometimes a little bit old fashioned (for example he doesn't use the Principled Shader there) but it's very very good and he is explaining literally everything - from modeling to materials.
So another good course I did and found useful was Environments on Udemy by Rob Tuytel - long, but cheap and you can learn much more advanced stuff. Like building a complex building and roads.
Also rule number one! Always do something for yourself - this way you ask questions and search the answers ;)